# running command on remote host by ssh fails when running inside script

Tags: ssh, scripts, reboot, remote

**The Situation:** 
My Computer runs on Kubuntu 14.04.
I am Admin of a Students House with some Netgear-APs.
The idea is to have a script rebooting them all by one script.
(ssh-key isn't posible)

**The Problem in short:** 
ssh command on host runs fine from shell. But not if run by a script.

**Description:** 
I have a Script on my Computer: "path/to/localScript"

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello mister"
reboot
```

now if I enter the following directly in my shell

```
    sshpass -p '[MYPASSWORD]' ssh [USER]@[HOST] < PATH/TO/LOCALSCRIPT
```

I get the output

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Hello mister
Connection to HOST closed by remote host.
```

and the AP actually reboots! I tried other commands(like ping) -> all worked fine.
Now I want to do exactly the same thing but inside a script (so I can later add all the other APs too ;) )
So I tried a script "rebootThemAll"

```
#!/bin/bash

echo " Rebooting AP 1"
sshpass -p '[MYPASSWORD]' ssh [USER]@[HOST] < PATH/TO/LOCALSCRIPT
```

I get the output

```
 Rebooting AP1 
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
```

and ... nothing more happens. Again I see my input prompt on the shell line so the script stops. I also tried more than 1 AP to see if that error cancels my script but it didn't. For more APs the output look like this

```
 Rebooting AP1
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
 Rebooting AP2
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
 Rebooting AP3
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
 Rebooting AP4
......
```

but the script won't run. It doesn't show the "Hello mister" and they are not rebooting..

Any one has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this problem using `-T` option "Disable pseudo-terminal allocation." and by using the scriptfiles without the `#!/bin/bash` line so just started with

```
echo "check" 
reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sshpass -p '[MYPASSWORD]' ssh [USER]@[HOST] 'bash -s' < PATH/TO/LOCALSCRIPT
```

It seems that command is needed in the case when there is no terminal at all.

[(found here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine)

Comment: wow sorry for this late repost .. didn't come back a long time
Thanks for your answer!
I could solve this problem using -T option "Disable pseudo-terminal allocation." and by using the Scriptfiles without the #!/bin/bash line
so just started with

echo "check"
reboot